# Importing the AWSCore header in application delegate - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, bridging-header

I'm following these instructions to integrate the AWS SDK in my swift app: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html

```
Import the AWSCore header in the application delegate:

#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
```

This instruction is confusing.

In my app delegate I have:

```
import "AWSCore/AWSCore.h"
```

This gives me an error:

```
Expected identifier in import declaration
```

How am I supposed to properly import the AWSCore header in the application delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at those instructions, I think the step where it says to add that line to your application delegate is in error, assuming your app delegate file is written in Swift.  (Besides, that line is in Objective-C syntax, not Swift.)

Because you already included that line in the bridging header, you don't have to add anything to any of your Swift files to use the AWS SDK -- it's included for you automatically.

Just leave it out and you should be fine!